# PHP Exec: Without Waiting, Without Discarding the Output, Without nohup

Tags: php, linux, exec, nohup

I need to run a command in PHP like this:

```
exec('dosomething > saveit.txt');
```

Except I don't want PHP to wait for it to be complete. I also don't want to throw away the output, and I don't want to use nohup because I'm using that for something else in the same directory.

I also tried `pclose(popen('dosomething > saveit.txt','r'));` and that didn't work, it still waited.

Comment: `nohup` can write to different output files. And if you immediately call `pclose` then the system of course must wait for the subprocess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add an [ampersand](http://lowfatlinux.com/linux-processes.html) to the end of the command, so:

```
exec('dosomething > saveit.txt &');
```

Comment: Do you know the equivalent for Windows system?

Answer (score 3):

in the documentation of [`exec()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) there is an interesting [comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php#101506) that says:

> Took quite some time to figure out the line I am going to post next. If you want to execute a command in the background without having the script waiting for the result, you can do the following:

```
 <?php
  passthru("/usr/bin/php /path/to/script.php ".$argv_parameter." >> /path/to/log_file.log 2>&1  &");
 ?>
```

Comment: Only problem is that I'm not trying to run another PHP script. But I can always make a PHP script with just the exec command in it, then run that PHP script with this. It's a solution.